# Why won't Lobster font work in my code on Codepen using Chromium Browser?

Tags: chromium, codepen

My question is about how to load Lobster font in my code on Codepen.io. Here is my HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

and CSS:

```
font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
```

Lobster font does not load and I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong. The HTML is in the head section. No other fonts will load either.
I've added Bootstrap 3 to the CSS settings.

I'm running the *Chromium* browser in **Ubuntu** 16.04.

Thank you for all help and suggestions.

Comment: Can you share the link to the code in question ? This would make easier to answer the question.

Comment: Here is the link to my pen on codepen 
        https://codepen.io/marcp78/pen/mLeRoy